# Solana CLI failing

Tags: solana-program, spl-token-cli

Why solana cli is not working on creating the tokens? It keeps on giving error "TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature XXXXXX has expired: block height exceeded."

Answer (score 0):

now a days solana having high traffic, if you dont send transaction without priority fee, transactions gets expired waiting to get added in blocks. Transaction having priority gets added on the blocks before transaction having no priority fee.

Comment: But cli doesn't support priority fees :(

Comment: It's being worked on!